# Less parses my grid mixin with comma's instead of periods

Tags: css, less

I use a grid mixin (Semantic.gs), that uses this code for columns:

```
.column(@x,@columns:@columns) {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: @total-width*((((@gutter-width+@column-width)*@x)-@gutter-width) / @gridsystem-width);
    margin: 5px @total-width*((@gutter-width*.5)/@gridsystem-width);
}
.full {
    .column(4);
}
```

^^ this code works on the live server, it generates this:

```
.full {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 99.1935483871%;
    margin: 5px 0.403225806452%;
}
```

On my local WAMP server it parses this, and breaks the whole layout:

```
.full {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 99,193548387097%;
    margin: 5px 0,40322580645161%;
}
```

Notice the comma's. The Less file has no errors, i checked. When i upload the Less file to the server it works fine. I use Windows 7, my language settings are that decimals points is a period. It has to be local, but i just don't know where to look!?

Comment: I guess you're using one of PHP Less ports (`lessphp`? `less.php`?) and I recall similar issue I saw before... Aside from trying to update the Less compiler of your WAMP server (this is clearly a bug and might be fixed with more recent versions), I suspect you also can set the correct decimal point somewhere in PHP config files...

Comment: Ok, this is weird, i did a new git pull, so it downloaded my files again, no plugin (lessphp) was updated, now it's all fixed. I am starting to think it had something to do with faulty code somewhere overwriting settings.. I did check your suggestions tho, thanks, it was all in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
It had to do with the foldername the site was running in my wamp.
I used "www.domain.nl" that made it behave weird.
Changed it to "domainnl" (without the periods), and it was fixed!

Thanks!